# using R's discrete.bayes with scalar data and vector prior

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm having trouble computing Bayesian posterior from some data. My data are basically one scalar: a difference between two means (df = a-b), which equals precisely 0.27, my prior is supposed to catch the intuition that df is positive (a is greater than b) and the greater df is, the more probable it is.

```
library("LearnBayes")
df = 0.27
prior = seq(1, 21, by=1)
names(prior) = seq(-.5, .5, by=.05)
prior = prior/sum(prior) #normalizing sum to 1
```

Yet `discrete.bayes(dbinom, prior, df, size=1)` produces NaNs. I tried to vectorize my df, but that doesn't work too:

```
y <- rep(0, 21)
names(y) <- seq(-.5, .5, by=.05)
y["0.25"] = 1
discrete.bayes(dbinom, prior, y, size=21)
```

It returns NaNs as well

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? (i.e. wrong sampling density method) Well, I gave this a lot of thought and I feel I'm in a fix. How should one work with prior and data of different formats?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `discrete.bayes(dbinom, …)` runs inference on the `p` parameter of the Binomial distribution; your prior specifies positive probability on negative values, which is not a valid prior on that parameter (since `p` represents a probability between zero and one).